# One label for multiuple inputs (radio)

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, label

```js
$('label').click(function() {
  id = this.id.split('-');

  if (id[0] === '1') {
    id[0] = '2';
  } else {
    id[0] = '1';
  }

  $('#' + id[0] + '-' + id[1]).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <input type="radio" id="1-1" name="1-level">
  <label for="1-1" id="1-1">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="1-2" name="1-level">
  <label for="1-2" id="1-2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <input type="radio" id="2-1" name="2-level">
  <label for="2-1" id="2-1">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="2-2" name="2-level">
  <label for="2-2" id="2-2">2</label>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have one label for multiple inputs (radio)? So if I press the label (e. q. for="1"), two input fields get checked (input with id 1 in div class one and two)? Here is my example:

```html
<div class="one">
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="level">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="level">
    <label for="2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="level">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="level">
    <label for="2">2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, using javascript

Comment: @Berto99 and pure css?

Comment: @Berto99 I've updated my code. Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from ducumentation:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

> The LABEL element may be used to attach information to controls. Each
>   LABEL element is associated with exactly one form control.

So only way to do what you asked is by using JS

HTML:
Use `data-input-group-id` instead of `id` and `data-for-input-group` instead of `for`. Also you'll now be able to use "1" and "2" not "1-1" etc.

JS:

```
$('[data-for-input-group]').click(function() {
   let inputGroupId = this.dataset.inputGroupId;
   $('[data-input-group-id = "'+inputGroupId+'"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: @ogm58191 Instead of using `id` and `for` I'd suggest using data attributes as you are rewriting default behavior of these attributes.

Comment: Can you give me an example :)?